# How to do a full outer join, when joining Sap tables with Excel in Crystal 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am  using Crystal 2008 
I am connecting to an excel sheet and SAP tables.

I would like to do a full outer join so that i can get all data from the SAP table and from the excel sheet. 

Is there anyway of doing this? 

Thanks 
Rachael

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Just to update everyone, The way I worked around this was to create two tables in SAGE.
One to take all the data from SAP, which I exported using Inaport.
The second table I created was for the excel sheet,
 so I had to edit the data in the excel sheet so I could import it into SAGE CRM. 
So a lot of messing around for a report 
but at least now I can do my full outer join.
```

Hope that helps someone.
Rachael